# Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null in expect function in testing-library (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a context. In the test, there is a test component that consumes the context. While testing the `expect` function (Mentioned in the comments), this error shows up

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

That actually doesn't make sense to me why it's null. I already tested the component separately to see how they look like, and nothing was wrong.

**Here is my code for the test, I mentioned in the comments what doesn't work**

```
    class CartContextTest extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            productName: '',
            priceInUSD: 0,
            priceInEUR: 0,
            attribute: ''
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <CartContextProvider>
                <CartContext.Consumer>
                    {context=>{
                        const {productsToPurchase, totalPrice, addProduct, decreaseProduct} = context

                        return(<>
                            <input type='text' title='product-name'
                                   onChange={ (e)=>{this.setState({productName: e.target.value})} }
                            />
                            <input type='text' title='price-in-usd'
                                   onChange={ (e)=>{this.setState({priceInUSD: e.target.value})} }
                            />
                            <input type='text' title='price-in-eur'
                                   onChange={ (e)=>{this.setState({priceInEUR: e.target.value})} }
                            />
                            <input type='text' title='attribute'
                                   onChange={ (e)=>{this.setState({attribute: e.target.value})} }
                            /> {/*There will be only ONE attribute for simplicity purposes*/}

                            <button title='add-product' onClick={()=>{
                                addProduct(this.state.productName,[{currency: 'USD', amount: this.state.priceInUSD},{currency: 'EUR', amount: this.state.priceInEUR}] , this.state.attribute)
                            }}>Add</button>

                            {/*This is must be rendered, but expect(queryByTitle("Name iphone-xr").innerHTML).toBe("iphone-xr") doesn't work*/}
                            {productsToPurchase.map(product=>{
                                return(<div>
                                    <h1 title={"Name " + product.itemId}>{product.itemId}</h1>
                                    <button title={"Plus " + product.itemId} onClick={()=>{addProduct(product.itemId, product.price, product.attributes)}}>+</button>
                                    <h1 title={"qty " + product.itemId}>{product.qty}</h1>
                                    <button title={"Minus " + product.itemId} onClick={()=>{decreaseProduct(product.itemId, product.attributes)}}>-</button>
                                    <>{product.price.map(price=>{
                                        return(<h1 title={price.currency + " " + product.itemId}>{price.amount}</h1>)
                                    })}</>
                                    <h1>{product.attributes}</h1>
                                </div>)
                            })}
                        </>)

                    }}
                </CartContext.Consumer>
            </CartContextProvider>
        );
    }
}

describe("Testing the ability to add and remove products from the cart", ()=>{

    const {queryByTitle} = render(<CartContextTest/>)
    const nameInput = queryByTitle("product-name")
    const usdInput = queryByTitle("price-in-usd")
    const eurInput = queryByTitle("price-in-eur")
    const attributeInput = queryByTitle("attribute")
    const addProductBtn = queryByTitle("add-product")

    it('All the starter components should be rendered', ()=> {
        expect(nameInput).toBeTruthy()
        expect(usdInput).toBeTruthy()
        expect(eurInput).toBeTruthy()
        expect(attributeInput).toBeTruthy()
        expect(addProductBtn).toBeTruthy()
    })

    it('Should add and remove products successfully', ()=>{

        // Add iPhone XR
        fireEvent.change(nameInput, {target:{value: "iphone-xr"}})
        fireEvent.change(usdInput, {target:{value: "600"}})
        fireEvent.change(eurInput, {target:{value: "500"}})
        fireEvent.change(attributeInput, {target:{value: "blue"}})
        fireEvent.click(addProductBtn)

        // This is the expect function that I talk about
        expect(queryByTitle("Name iphone-xr").innerHTML).toBe("iphone-xr")

    })
})
```

Comment: Have you tested what product.itemID is anywhere?

Comment: @user1280483 yes and it works as I expected

Comment: @user1280483 did you get the solution? I still didn't find it

Answer (score 0):

1. Attach an identifier like `className` or something of choice to your class-based component
2. Asynchronously render the component
3. Use basic DOM methods like `querySelector` to work with the componented rendered as an HTML element

[Reference 1](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/)

[Reference 2](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/)

```js
    class CartContextTest extends React.Component {

    //..
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
            <CartContextProvider>
               //...
            </CartContextProvider>
        );
    }
}




describe("Testing the ability to add and remove products from the cart", ()=>{
    //...
    it('Should add and remove products successfully', async()=>{
       await render(<CartContextTest/>)
       const queryByTitle = document.querySelector(".container")

        //...

        // This is the expect function that I talk about
        expect(queryByTitle.innerHTML).toBe("iphone-xr")

    })
})
```

Comment: That actually outputs null, why is that? It means that it's not rendered at all. Why?

Comment: It is because there is no such thing as `render(<CartContextTest/>)`. It has no meaning in JS. It's an invalid syntax causing a null output. Just do `const queryByTitle=<CartContextTest/>` or `const queryByTitle=CartContextTest.render()` and tell me how it works

Comment: I tried both of them, and both were not valid functions. `queryByTitle is not a function` and so..

Comment: The render function was for `testing library` as I imported here `import {render, fireEvent} from "@testing-library/react"`

Comment: Then in that case, `queryByTitle` queries by something which you put in the `<title/>` or svg title tag as given here (https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/)  . So here it is a wrong usage . Can you pls try making the callback function to describe as `async` as I have done in the `edited` version of this answer ?

Comment: Where can I see the edited version?

Comment: check this answer only now

Comment: I'm getting a red underline under `async `

Comment: What does it say on hovering on the red line ?

Comment: `ESLint: No async describe callback(jest/valid-describe)`

Comment: Got it. Check latest edit to this ans and tell me

Comment: I'm now getting this error `TypeError: queryByTitle is not a function`

Comment: Check now. This should work

Comment: It also, gives me the same error

Comment: I think `fireEvent.click(addProductBtn)` doesn't click the button